# How to require one of many modules in your own module?

Tags: 7

Let's say my module needs functionality X. This functionality can be provided by two other modules. For example, front-end with two backends to store data, and at least one backend is needed for frontend to work. Is there a way in Drupal to mark it?

In GNU/Linux and BSD operating systems there usually is a marker like `provides`, for example Bison provides Yacc, and everything that would need a Yacc can work with only Bison installed. That's about what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Polymorphic modules - now that would be fun :) I'm almost 100% positive no such mechanism exists at the moment

Comment: How do these other modules provide the functionality? Does your module explicitly call them or is there a hook?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Now it does not - that's why I was looking for a Drupal way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. Please explain how your module makes use of these other modules (direct call or via a hook, or what?)

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong I want to keep it universal. Scenarios are: Main module provides interface and needs at least one class implementing it to exist; invokes a hook and needs at least one module to implement it. And alike. You know, like form module useless without any module to actually save results. MPD's answer seems to satisfy this already and is universal enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to feature detect the modules using [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) or [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php), and then use some logic to pick the one you want.

You can also wire up a [`hook_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7) to hard fail in the `$phase == 'install'` step or soft fail in the `$phase == 'runtime'` step.

How you handle the failures really depends on your application.